# PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901769/warning-strpos-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-resource), I see where the `$handle = @fopen($thumb, 'r');` was changed to `$handle = @file_get_contents($thumb);` because he needed to use file_get_contents for a string.

I am getting the same error but I do not see a fopen() element that needs to be changed?  Where does this need to occur?

```
} elseif( strpos($post_id, 'user_') !== false ) {

    $user_id = str_replace('user_', '', $post_id);
    $user_id = intval( $user_id );

    $v = get_user_meta( $user_id, $field['name'], false );

    // value is an array
    if( isset($v[0]) ) {

        $value = $v[0];

    }
```

Comment: before strpos, use var_dump($post_id) for see the value of variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error $post_id is an array. An example of [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

```
$mystring = 'abc';
$findme   = 'a';
$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);
```

In your code `print_r($post_id)` to see containing values

```
 strpos($post_id, 'user_')//here $post_id is array
```

Answer (score 1):

Function `strpos()` is used to compare strings and you have passed an array as the first parameter.

`$post_id` may be an array.