# strrpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use the upload library of CodeIgniter but I keep on getting an error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: strrpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Filename: libraries/Upload.php

Line Number: 1178

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolPortal\application\controllers\StudentAffairs.php
Line: 207
Function: do_upload

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\schoolPortal\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I don't know what's the error because I just copied the same code in other function of the same controller, but that one is working.

Here is a sample of the code in the controller:

```
            $img_name = $this->InfoModel->getFirstNullAnnouncement();

            $config['upload_path']          = './images/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 5000;
            $config['max_width']            = 3000;
            $config['max_height']           = 4000;
            $config['overwrite']            = TRUE;
            $config['file_name']            = $img_name;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $img = "userfile";

            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $user['user'] = $this->UsersModel->select_student_affairs($id);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload($img)){
                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

                $this->load->view('include/header_student_affairs',$user);
                $this->load->view('studentaffairs/add_announcement', $data);
                $this->load->view('include/footer_student_affairs');
            } else {
                $img_path = 'images/'.$this->upload->data('orig_name');
                $data['success'] = 'Announcement has been updated.';
                $data['announcements'] = $this->InfoModel->getAnnouncements();
                $data['announcenum'] = $this->InfoModel->getAnnouncementCount();

                $this->InfoModel->updateAnnouncement($img_path);

                $imgdata = $this->upload->data();
                $thumbnail = $imgdata['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$imgdata['file_ext'];
                $this->createThumbnail($img_path, $img_id, $thumbnail);

                $this->load->view('include/header_student_affairs',$user);
                $this->load->view('studentaffairs/announcements', $data);
                $this->load->view('include/footer_student_affairs');
            }
```

Line 207 is this one:

```
if (!$this->upload->do_upload($img)){
```

The `$this->upload->display_errors();` produces an error: T`he filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.`

Please help

Comment: Can you add the code for the do_upload method? try to show us the flow till get to the strrpos method. Also what is the name of the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: The do_upload method is in the upload library of codeigniter

Comment: The error is in `upload.php` file. Where is it? In the meantime  Check this  http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php

Comment: @aronccs I understand that. You will have to navigate in the CI code, so you can understand how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432506/php-warning-strpos-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given)

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the Upload.php in CI's library since I can upload an image in another function

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the extension of your file that about to upload is `.jpeg` which is not on the list of `$config['allowed_types']`..